# Customer update SOAP action

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v1

I need a point in the right direction. 
Right now we have a SOAP V1 API grabbing customers when they create an order. I have been asked to also be able to update a customer when the save new profile information. So basically when they click the save button on the update profile page. 
I have not deat with a lot of SOAP V1 actions and am looking for some resources into how I would write this out to be performed when this button is clicked.
I know this isn't a normal SE question, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you only have access to the API? Or the ability to make a module in Magento? Because ideally you'd use the <customer_save_after> event to push to your external service. Otherwise, if only API, there's no hook events for this, so you'd effectively have to poll the customer collection periodically checking for changes, which may be slow if a large customer base.

Comment: I would like to make it so we don't have to poll the database for changes. So if creating a module is what needs to be done in order to have each time a customer update happens, the information is posted to the API that would be the way to go.

Comment: You'd need to make an event observer. Here's a guide that I've just found, which may help you http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-event-observer-with-save-before-and-save-after/